# Talk to VLC from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlc

When playing video in normal, standalone VLC Player, I wish to get the current timecode in Excel. In VBA I've added the ***VideoLAN VLC ActiveX Plugin*** reference, and the isolated code is below.

```
Sub vlcTest()
    Dim myVLC As New AXVLC.VLCPlugin2
    MsgBox myVLC.input.Time
End Sub
```

This always returns `-1`, meaning there's nothing there. I'm wondering if this is intended to interact with an embedded instance of VLC.... but I need it to work with the regular standalone VLC Player. All advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: I dont know about vlc but I guess you need to 'tell' your object how to connect to an instance of vlc? As in 'set myVlc= something'

Comment: OK... I'm trying to figure out how to do that...

Comment: To get the HWND handle of a VLC instance, it may be easier to launch it from VBA.

Comment: Sadly I need to be able to read from an existing instance of VLC. This is a little beyond me, I'm struggling to figure it out... I realise now my question is of the "hey please write code for me" ilk :-S. I'll keep trying to figure it out...